# Is there a way to block certain vertices in a curve / path from being modified

Tags: modeling

I have a curve that I'm editing but I only want to modify the bottom half of it, and the other half to remain without changes. But if I subdivide the bottom the top half changes, if I move a vertex too much on the bottom part the top also changes.

Hiding the vertices I don't want to modify don't works. I'm working with a curve using a circle as a bevel to create a tube.

Comment: I guess we need more information in which way "the top half changes". What @Chris suggested may have an influence on moving the vertices, but not subdividing the curve. If you say the top changes when you subdivide the bottom, you mean it gets subdivided too? Or does it change its shape? Screenshots would be helpful to explain what problems you have. Or why does hiding the top vertices not help? Usually hiding curve vertices still shows the curve, but keeps the vertices from being modified. Do you have any other modifiers on that curve?

Comment: Before subdividing the bottom: https://imgur.com/a/ZcG7Q8v
After subdividing the bottom: https://imgur.com/a/vjQiHV2

The 2 curves are the same object just rotated. Notice how the top curvature changes if I subdivide the 2 vertices on the bottom

Comment: Oh, the curvature of the geometry changes... not the curve itself. The vertices and connections inbetween defining the curve all stay the same. Of course the curvature changes - it's a _Nurbs_ curve or something similar if I see it correctly. The curvature is dependent on the underlying segments and just like, for example, the _Subdivision Surface_ modifier changes shape when you add geometry like loop cuts etc., on your curve more segments result in a differently shaped geometry.

Comment: You see, the added vertices on the long vertical path force the geometry to go up straight higher, but since the top curve stays the same, the geometry has to bend more to reach the end point while before adding vertices it was "allowed" to bend less sharp.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) Don't add them in the comments where they are easy to miss, [edit] them into your original post.